# Starting applications from terminal prints funny messages on terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

Whenever I start Firefox or any other application from command line it prints messages on the terminal. How do I get rid of those messages? Where should I redirect those things and how?

I use this to start firefox.

`$ firefox &`

What should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect them to `/dev/null`.

```
firefox &> /dev/null &
```